# Overwrite file if new session but append if same session

Tags: powershell

I have a function to convert any `write-hosts` in the script (keeping them for coloring purposes later) to `tee` object

```
function Write-Host($object) 
{
    $object | tee .\LOG.txt -Append
}
```

This currently appends to the file if it exists (or creates one if it doesnt)

i want to create one everytime a NEW session is started. only append to the file if you are in the same session

how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where global variables are useful, because they can persist through the entire session. In this example I am using them to set the unique filename (in this case today's date), to log to:

```
function Write-Host($object) 
{
    if($global:LogFile -eq $null)
    {
        $global:LogFile = ".\LOG-$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd').txt"
    }

    $object | tee $global:LogFile -Append
}
```

--- Edit: ---

From comments, if you want to have a new file on the start of session, and append during the session, we can still use the global variable to determine the start of a session, but we simply use the check to remove the file at the start, and leave the Append to the Tee:

```
function Write-Host($object) 
{
    if($global:LogFile -eq $null)
    {
        $global:LogFile = ".\LOG.txt"
        Remove-Item $global:LogFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    $object | tee $global:LogFile -Append
}
```

--- Edit 2: ---

From second Comments:

`Remove-Item` is a different animal because it has no output by default. Indeed, the only way to get any output is to add the `-Verbose` parameter. But the `Tee-Object` doesn't capture the Verbose stream. To get around this, we have to use two tricks. First, we specify the `-Verbose` parameter (to get an output), with a redirect ([about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)), to redirect the Verbose stream (4) to the standard Success (1) / Information stream. This would allow the `Tee-Object` to capture the information from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
Remove-Item test.txt -Verbose 4>&1 | Tee-Object out.txt
```

Comment: of course, i did think of the datestamp idea but i dont want tons of log files, so thats why i am looking for something else, to overwrite the file everytime a new session is entered

Comment: isnt there something more of if($PSsession -eq new) {...} else {-append}

Comment: Question: i have somewhere later in my code Remove_item $_ -verbose. it prints to console "Performing remove operation on file..." but its not appending this statement to the log file. is there a way to make -verbose append globally same as i have for Write-Host? btw, thanks for the update, its working perfectly as i intended :)

Comment: Please see Edit 2, for how to capture `Remove-Item` information.

Comment: this works generally speaking. however, it doesnt printo to console but only to the file. can you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364249/why-is-verbose-redirection-creating-a-line-between-data-in-exported-csv-file

Comment: When I ran the straight `Remove-Item` command as above (on PS v5.1) I saw output both on console and in the file as expected. Can you post a new question to SO with your code because I would like to reproduce the issue you see?

Comment: is it possibly becaus eim using just tee? im not using tee-object

Comment: heres a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364249/why-is-verbose-redirection-creating-a-line-between-data-in-exported-csv-file

Comment: I see the issue you are having. I have replied to that post with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define what a new "session" is to you, so let's use the variable `$PID`, which is the process ID that PowerShell is running as.

Ideally you'd just make this part of the file name so that each process has its own log. But you stated in comments that you don't want multiple files. In that case, write the PID as the first line in the file, and read it each time.

```bsh
function Write-Host($object) 
{
    $filename = '.\LOG.txt'

    $logPID = Get-Content -LiteralPath $filename -ReadCount 1 -ErrorAction Ignore
    $newSession = $logPID -ne $PID

    if ($newSession) {
        $PID | Set-Content -LiteralPath $filename
    }

    $object | Tee-Object -FilePath $filename -Append
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer an alternative method for future searchers. You can get what time your current process started at, compare it to when the file was created, and delete the file if it was created before your current PID was started.

```
function Write-Host
{
[cmdletbinding()]
Param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$object)
Begin{
    $allObjects=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
}
Process{
    $allObjects.Add($object)|out-null
}
End{
    if((test-path .\log.txt) -and (get-item '.\LOG.txt').CreationTime -lt (Get-Process -Id $PID).StartTime){Remove-Item .\LOG.txt}
    $allObjects | tee .\LOG.txt -Append
}
}
```

Plus with the conversion to an advanced function you can just pipe things to it, such as:

```
Get-Process | Write-Host
```

Or I suppose the simplest thing to do is just delete the log file as the first thing your script does.

Comment: hey if you dont mind, can you check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351076/how-to-pipe-tee-with-verbose