# How to pipe tee with -Verbose?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the following

```
$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_"; Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose | tee .\log.txt -Append} | 
            Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -force
```

I can see the verbose output on console but tee is not appending anything to the log file. How can I tee the -verbose output to the file? (VERBOSE: performing remove operation on file...)

Comment: This should help you [Programmatically capture Verbose Output](http://blog.simonw.se/programmatically-capture-verbose-output-in-a-powershell-variable)

Comment: @Olaf hmm i see. so i'd have to store it in a variable first afterall huh? like this: $VerboseMessage = $($_ = Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_") 4>&1

Comment: No, just redirect the verbose output to standard output (`;Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 4>&1|tee .\log.txt -append}`, and pipe that to the `tee-object`, but with what you're doing you don't want to do that since that would pass that message down the pipeline along with the CSV data, and then the `Export-Csv` wouldn't know what to do with `VERBOSE: Performing remove...`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician its kinda working but its creating a line in between the two different servers in the csv file thats exported.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56351076/edit) your question to update the code you are using, and give an example of the issue you are facing. Right now I'm thinking you need to change `tee` to `add-content`, but its hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This done the trick

```
Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_" | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -Force;
    Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append
}
```